# Legend for more than a single geom having single category

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have the following plot created using ggplot and plotly:

[image]

It is created using a combination of geom_bar and geom_point. The thing is that I would like to show in a legend that the black points are Medians and the red bars are averages. Is it possible at all? I know that within the geoms it is straightforward using the fill and shape, but I'm lost when it comes to labeling different geoms.

This is the code that generates it:

```
p <- ggplot(data=MoltdenDataset,aes(Level = LEVELNUMBER,Metric=value)) +
  geom_bar(data = MoltdenDataset[variable=="Average",] , aes(x=as.factor(LEVELNUMBER),y=value) , width = 0.5 , position = position_dodge(width=0.5) , stat="identity" , fill = "#FF4500") +
  geom_point(data = MoltdenDataset[variable=="Median",] , aes(x=as.factor(LEVELNUMBER),y=value))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to make some progress by abusing the aesthetic system a little. Set the point color to the literal string "Median" and fill color to "Average", then set your colors using `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_color_manual`:

```
p <- ggplot(data=MoltdenDataset,aes(Level = LEVELNUMBER,Metric=value)) +
  geom_bar(data = MoltdenDataset[variable=="Average",] , aes(x=as.factor(LEVELNUMBER),y=value, fill = 'Average') , width = 0.5 , position = position_dodge(width=0.5) , stat="identity") +
  geom_point(data = MoltdenDataset[variable=="Median",] , aes(x=as.factor(LEVELNUMBER),y=value, color = 'Median')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = '#FF4500') +
  scale_color_manual(values = '#000000')
```

Alternately, you could create a data frame with your intended key values (labels, x, and y coordinates), and use `geom_text` to place those into the plot.